# Holidays output

Tags: curated-data, date-and-time

I wanted to print out the holidays in Germany in 2016:

```
DayRange[DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}], 
 DateObject[{2016, 12, 31}], "Holiday", 
 HolidayCalendar -> {"Germany", "Bavaria"}]
```

The result list is:

```
{DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 3, 25}], 
 DateObject[{2016, 3, 28}], DateObject[{2016, 12, 26}]}
```

More curious for France:

```
DayRange[DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}], 
 DateObject[{2016, 12, 31}], "Holiday", HolidayCalendar -> "France"]
```

The holiday list is empty:

```
{}
```

**Since this is not true, I would like to ask where the error is.** Do you find the same problem for your country?

The full list of the Bavarian holidays is:

[image]

The output for USA is much longer:

```
DayRange[DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}], 
 DateObject[{2016, 12, 31}], "Holiday", 
 HolidayCalendar -> "UnitedStates"]

{DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2016, 1, 18}], 
 DateObject[{2016, 2, 15}], DateObject[{2016, 5, 30}], 
 DateObject[{2016, 7, 4}], DateObject[{2016, 9, 5}], 
 DateObject[{2016, 10, 10}], DateObject[{2016, 11, 11}], 
 DateObject[{2016, 11, 24}], DateObject[{2016, 12, 26}]}
```

Comment: Probably something for WRI support, possibly also for Wolfram Alpha feedback.

Comment: I informed them ...